# What is the most idiomatic way to concatenate integer variables?

Tags: string, concatenation, rust

The compiler doesn't seem to infer that the integer variables are passed as string literals into the `concat!` macro, so I found the `stringify!` macro that converts these integer variables into string literals, but this looks ugly:

```
fn date(year: u8, month: u8, day: u8) -> String
{
    concat!(stringify!(month), "/",
            stringify!(day), "/",
            stringify!(year)).to_string()
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`concat!` takes literals and produces a `&'static str` at *compile* time. You should use `format!` for this:

```
fn date(year: u8, month: u8, day: u8) -> String {
    format!("{}/{}/{}", month, day, year)
}
```

Comment: Ohh, good one, thanks! I'll accept this as the answer when it lets me. This makes concat! pretty worthless in my opinion, they should take it out to keep a smaller, orthogonal set of features in the language.

Comment: @elleciel: Actually, in a language where performance matters, `concat!` is essential: a `&'static str` does not require a memory allocation, and can be stored in read-only memory.

Comment: @elleciel: `concat!` is not a commonly-used feature, but it’s something of value in macros occasionally.

Answer (score 4):

Also note that your example **does not do what you want**! When you compile it, you get these warnings:

```
<anon>:1:9: 1:13 warning: unused variable: `year`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
<anon>:1 fn date(year: u8, month: u8, day: u8) -> String
                 ^~~~
<anon>:1:19: 1:24 warning: unused variable: `month`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
<anon>:1 fn date(year: u8, month: u8, day: u8) -> String
                           ^~~~~
<anon>:1:30: 1:33 warning: unused variable: `day`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
<anon>:1 fn date(year: u8, month: u8, day: u8) -> String
                                      ^~~
```

Note that all the variables are unused! The output of calling the function will *always* be the string:

```
month/day/year
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize that was the purpose of the `stringify!` macro, I see interesting use for this.